# how to fill the DIV container with elements based on container's actual size?

Tags: layout, dynamic

I have a DIV container somewhere on the page with min-width and min-height set to some values.

I am loading small panels (DIVs with display:inline-block) into it using callbacks and javascript.

Right now the number of panels is fixed, so that when the user maximizes the browser window, the size of the container increases, and white space appears at the end of last line.

I want to catch the container's size changes, and load more elements, as many as will fit without clipping into the container's new space.

I saw this on amazon.com. They have panels that display 4 products, but if the browser window is maximized, same panels will display more products filling all the available space in the container.

Scroll-bars must not appear, and no clipping of elements must be done.

Is there a script I could use, or sample code?

Thank you,
Andrei

Comment: showing us the code would help!

Comment: Is the size of the child-containers fixed? Or are they dynamic as well?

Comment: Ultimately a browser will fit block-level elements like `div`s within a container based on the constraining size of those block-level elements. So in your page layout, what sizes have you specified and which resize themselves?

Comment: I don't have the code right now. But here you can see how it works now: [link http://www.megabit-mich.ru/](http://www.megabit-mich.ru/) You can see the three "displays" as I call the containing 8 elements each. When the browser window is increased, you can see the white space appearing, which I want to fill with more elements (products) fetching them from the server via callback.

Comment: Daan, the width of the child elements is fixed, the height is not.

Comment: Piers, the elements do not resize, they remain the same size after they have benn created. Only the size of the container changes, as the browser window size changes.

Comment: Right, will try to answer this tomorrow, seeing my webserver had crashed where I had written an example on >_> (crashed it by own fault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very nice solution to the problem.
Here's the code: (term 'display' here is used in the same sense as at the supermarket):

```
function updateDisplay() {
    $(".s2", this).hide();
    var x = $(".s2", this);

    var prevPos = -1;
    var nrows = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        $(x[i]).toggle();
        var curPos = $(x[i]).position().left;
        if (curPos < prevPos) {
            if (--nrows == 0) {
                $(x[i]).toggle();
                break;
            }
        }
        prevPos = curPos;
    }
}

function updateDisplays() {
    $(".dcon").each(updateDisplay);
}

$(window).resize(updateDisplays);
$(document).ready(updateDisplays);
```

You can see it in action on the following pages:

[www.megabit-mich.ru](http://www.megabit-mich.ru)

[www.sportolimpia.ru](http://www.sportolimpia.ru)